# SQL Server select for update empty value

Tags: sql-server

Hi I tried to update an image in a `varbinary` column with the following example [How to insert a blob into a database using sql server management studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643627/how-to-insert-a-blob-into-a-database-using-sql-server-management-studio)

Yet to do a select after doing update the `varbinary` column is blank, any idea why this happens?

```
UPDATE digital_files
   SET digital_file = (
        SELECT *
          FROM OPENROWSET( BULK N'C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.26\bin\celebrity-pictures-spongebob-patrick-meth-that.jpg',
                           SINGLE_BLOB) AS IMAGE)
WHERE digital_id = 1
```

Comment: Thanks Richard, the code is:

" UPDATE digital_files
SET digital_file = (SELECT *
FROM OPENROWSET(
BULK N'C:\Program Files (x86)\Apache Software Foundation\Apache Tomcat 6.0.26\bin\celebrity-pictures-spongebob-patrick-meth-that.jpg',
SINGLE_BLOB) AS IMAGE)
WHERE digital_id = 1 "
 
But the field appears blank :(

Comment: What does the select itself return if you execute just that?

Comment: when I do a select field after running digital_files update the field is completely blank me, if I give a LEN digital_files I realize it does have a size, I just do not know if I saved the image correctly, I have seen in other pages which should have are 0x .... Any ideas?