# Insert Large Objects into Azure SQL Data warehouse

Tags: blob, azure-synapse

I have created a table in Azure SQL Data Warehouse as below:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.test_lob_type
(
    id          VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    mime_type   VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
    binary_lob  VARBINARY(MAX) NULL
)
WITH
(
    DISTRIBUTION = HASH ( id ), 
    CLUSTERED INDEX ( id ASC )
);
```

I want to insert a BLOB object into this table.  I tried to achieve this using the `OPENROWSET` command as pointed in the link [How to insert a blob into a database using sql server management studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643627/how-to-insert-a-blob-into-a-database-using-sql-server-management-studio)

But unfortunately this command does not work with Azure SQL DW. Can anyone provide any input on how to insert any BLOB object into a SQL DW table from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

[bcp](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) is supported for this scenario.  Here is a simple example using SQL Authentication and char format:

```
REM Example using SQL Authentication and character file
bcp dbo.test_lob_type in test_lob_type.bcp -S yourDWServer.database.windows.net -d yourDWName -U yourLogin -P yourPassword -c
```

If your file only contains the blob, consider loading to a staging table before inserting into the main table.