# Insert a file PDF in a table SQL server using management studio

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to insert data in next table:
[Table Of Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvWMR.png)

I'm using Management Studio, but i don't know how to relate the file inserted with the column which has the ID number (in my case is named 'Batch'). All examples that I've found are like this without that column :

```
CREATE TABLE nameTable(fileReport varbinary(max)) 
INSERT INTO nameTable (fileReport) SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\File1.pdf', SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB
```

Comment: I tried reformatting your SQL to make it a bit easier to read but I cannot tell if that second line (staring with `{INSERT INTO` should be two lines or one.

Comment: I re-edit the question, look at it

Comment: Have you seen this [Q & A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1643627/how-to-insert-a-blob-into-a-database-using-sql-server-management-studio)?  I think it may address your question.

Comment: Oh and make sure that file path you're specifying (in `OPENROWSET`) is a file path on _the_ _server_ not your client.

Comment: Yes Onorio, it is in the server. the problem is that I don't know  what is the syntax to add the other data, because it creates a table with one column. I tried many ways and there is always a mistake. I'm going to check Q & A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, if I understand your question correctly the answer would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO nametable
            (batch,
             filereport)
VALUES      ('batch_number1',
             (SELECT *
              FROM   OPENROWSET(BULK 'c:\File1.pdf', single_blob) AS fileReport)
)
```

I think your issue is that you're not doing the `VALUES` clause on your `INSERT` statement

By the way, credit where it's due; I got that answer from this [web page](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/walzenbach/2010/05/20/how-to-insert-binary-data-like-imagesdocuments-into-a-sql-server-database-with-sql-server-management-studio/)